# data frame with column character type doesn't work with rbind

Tags: r

I'm trying to instantiate a data frame and then insert rows into it. One of the columns will contain strings. I had issues with the strings being considered factors, and then when a new string appears R would insert `NA` instead. So I had to use the following workaround:

```
df = data.frame(x = character(3), stringsAsFactors = F)
df = rbind(df, c('foo'))
df = rbind(df, c('bar'))
df
#    x
#1    
#2    
#3    
#4 foo
#5 bar
```

however it's not good because I don't want to have empty rows. However the following does not work:

```
df = data.frame(x = character(0), stringsAsFactors = F)
df = rbind(df, c('foo'))
df = rbind(df, c('bar'))
#Warning message:
#In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "bar") :
#  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I know I can use `df[i, ] = c(...)` instead but I don't want to keep track of indices.

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = F` in your `rbind`. Or set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: `rbind` is intended to union together two data frames.  This is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is the closest answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `rbind` to join data.frames with same column names

```
df = data.frame(x = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df = rbind(df, data.frame(x = c('foo')))
df = rbind(df, data.frame(x = c('bar')))
df
#    x
#1 foo
#2 bar
```

Comment: it's really confusing why this works and rbind(df, c('foo')) followed by rbind(df, c('bar'))  does not

Comment: @cosmos1990 `rbind` takes two data frame/list arguments, not a data frame and a vector.  There is magic happening the way you call `rbind`, perhaps not to your favor.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `list`:

```
rbind(df, list(x=c("foo","bar")))
#    x
#1 foo
#2 bar
```

Answer (score 2):

`rbind` by default have `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.  So, use the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to avoid converting to `factor` class

According to `?rbind`

> rbind(..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE,
>         stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

```
df <- rbind(df, list(x='foo'), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
df <- rbind(df, list(x = 'bar'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   x
#1 foo
#2 bar

str(df)
#'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ x: chr  "foo" "bar"
```

Instead of repeatedly using the `stringsAsFactors`, we can also change it in the `options`.

Here we assume that the OP wanted to sequentially add the rows and based on the OP's initialization of `data.frame` ('df'), the column class would be `character` class

Comment: can you please add why stringsAsFactors=TRUE is needed as a parameter to rbind instead of when initializing the data frame?

Comment: @cosmos1990  Because `rbind` has `stringsAsFactors` parameter and it will pick up the default option whether it is TRUE or FALSE.  If you don't specify it in the `options`, it will be TRUE by default.  Also, I assumed that you wanted a dataset with column as `character` based on your initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a `tidy` approach

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(x = character(0))


df <- bind_rows(df, c("x" = "foo"))
df <- bind_rows(df, c("x" = "bar"))
df

# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#       x
#   <chr>
# 1   foo
# 2   bar
```

Comment: Or if you wanted to shorten it slightly thelatemail's answer inside `bind_rows` also works `bind_rows(list(x=c("foo","bar")))`